# Where is Tosafot about Tarti Dsasri

Tags: tefilla, zemanim, mincha-afternoon-prayer, tosfot

The Tiferet Shmuel to the Rosh (Berachot 4:3) quotes a Tosafot to allow inconsistant practice (*tarti tsatri*) as to Mincha after Plag versus Maariv after Plag in a case of *torech hatzibbur* (inconveinience to the congregation). I can't find this Tosafos. So which tosafos discusses torech tzibbur in connection to permitting self contradictory practice?

Comment: 1st one in Shas might be the one (asks the question but might not have the answer there - could be a Tosafos we don't have)

Comment: @naftali tzi, Did you check the Tosafos Harash?